# How to specify that a file should be fetched if either its content length is greater than the local copy or it has been modified since?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I know how to make a request that says "fetch the file only if it has been modified since a specific date".

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.create(url);
request.IfModifiedSince = lastWriteTime; // lastWriteTime is the time when 
                                         // the local file was last written.

try
 {
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    ...
```

But, suppose this scenario occurs -

the local file is not modified since the last write time, but when it was downloaded from the server the last time, **the file was incomplete**. In other words, the content length in the local file is not the same as the content length in the file on the server.

So I would like to specify that the file should be fetched from the server, if the content length on the server is not the same as the content length on the local machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want any way to do this or You need to do this with HttpWebRequesty only ?

Comment: HttpWebRequest would be preferable. But if not, I know how to do it the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

For Your scenario and with HTTP only I would check file length header:

```
        string length = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength];
```

So You will know right from the start what length this file should have. If it's too short then it's not complete and You need to download again.

If You are more concerned about content of file You can check also MD5:

```
        string md5 = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentMd5];
```

If You insist on request condition You can try HTTP header **If-Range**. It is described by W3C as:

> ...
>   Informally, its meaning is `if the entity is unchanged, send me the part(s) that I am missing; otherwise, send me the entire new entity'.
>   ...

Check [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and [HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) to see what Your options are.